# How to distinguish Shake-Up Satellites from Plasmons?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, spectroscopy, photoelectric-effect

I am studying XPS spectra (X-ray Photoelectron Spectroscopy) at the moment. In XPS, different processes can influence the final state energy of detected electrons.

One of these processes is the plasmon loss in which the emitted electrons lose energy to a collective excitation of the conduction band electrons.

My questions is now: How can we experimentally distinguish this effect from a usual shake-up process where the emitted electron loses energy to a valence band electron by exciting it to a higher level?